# Java graphics cannot relocate rectangle

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to relocate a rectangle but for I cannot figure out why it stays in the same location.
It creates a red rectangle but does not change color or move to a new location.

Here is my code:

```
package grap_prj.dom.shenkar;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class graphic_main extends JPanel{

static Rectangle rec = new Rectangle ();

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    rec.setSize(10, 10);
    rec.setLocation(10, 10);

    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2d.drawRect((int)rec.getX(),(int)rec.getY(), 10, 10);
    g2d.fillRect((int)rec.getX(),(int)rec.getY(), 10, 10);
}

public static void update_ui (Graphics g)
{
    System.out.println("in update");
    rec.setLocation(50, 50);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawRect((int)rec.getX(),(int)rec.getY(), 10, 10);
    g2d.fillRect((int)rec.getX(),(int)rec.getY(), 10, 10);  
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Graphics");
    frame.add(new graphic_main());
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    graphic_main.update_ui(frame.getGraphics());
    frame.revalidate();
 }
}
```

Update: 
I have made a few changes in the code, but still the same situation. I change the location but a new rectangle is added instead of moving the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are continuosly setting location at 10,10 so the rectangle will always be drawn at 10,10.

After setting location 50,50 you aren't drawing anything. Next step you will set 10,10 again.

Comment: I have made a few changes in the code, please have a look.
Another rectangle is drawn instead of replacing the existing one.

Comment: @user3394478 Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904807/repaint-doesnt-clear-the-frame

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you override `paintComponent()`, you need to call `super.paintComponent()`.

You are also calling `repaint()` from `repaint()`.  You need to decide on some action that will cause it to repaint.

Comment: I have made a few changes in the code, please have a look.
Another rectangle is drawn instead of replacing the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should never call `update()` or `repaint()` inside of a `paintComponent(...)` method. Ever. This risks recursion or ineffective uncontrolled animation.
2. Don't change the state of your object inside of a paint or paintComponent method. You don't have full control over when or even if these methods get called.
3. Don't forget to call the super's method inside your paintComponent override to allow the JPanel to do its housekeeping graphics including erasing old dirty pixels.
4. Even though you change the Graphics context's Color to blue, it will change right back to red anytime the paintComponent is called. So your color change is futile code. Solution: make the Color a variable that can be set.
5. If you want to do Swing animation, use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

---

For an example of Swing animation, have a look at my example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909952/522444).

---

For another example, have a look at this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleAnimation extends JPanel {

   private static final int PREF_W = 800;
   private static final int PREF_H = 650;
   private static final Color[] COLORS = { Color.red, Color.orange,
         Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.blue, Color.magenta };
   private static final int RECT_WIDTH = 40;
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 10;
   private int x = 0;
   private int y = 0;
   private int colorIndex = 0;
   private Color color = COLORS[colorIndex];

   public SimpleAnimation() {
      new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(color);
      g.fillRect(x, y, RECT_WIDTH, RECT_WIDTH);
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         x++;
         y++;
         if (x + RECT_WIDTH > getWidth()) {
            x = 0;
         }
         if (y + RECT_WIDTH > getHeight()) {
            y = 0;
         }
         if (x % 40 == 0) {
            colorIndex++;
            colorIndex %= COLORS.length;
            color = COLORS[colorIndex];
         }
         repaint();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleAnimation");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new SimpleAnimation());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I have made a few changes in the code, please have a look.
Another rectangle is drawn instead of replacing the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Your changing the location before the frame gets the chance to render it. So its creating it at 10, 10 and then when its rendered changes it to 50 50 then to 10, 10.